# Best way to compare value in register with constant assembly AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, assembly

I am new to assembly and AVR. What is the best way to compare two values like in C:

```
#define SOME_VAL 55
int current_counter = 0;
...
...
if(current_counter==SOME_VAL) {

}
```

In assembly I have the following code:

```
.EQU SOME_VAL = 55

.def current_counter = r19
```

What is the best way to compare the current value with a defined constant?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use C? avr-gcc is pretty damn good. Also, an easy answer to "how do I do this C thing in assembly?" is to write it in C, compile it, and see what was generated.

Comment: ^^This, writing any assembly without reason is pretty silly in 2015.

Comment: I took a course in microprocessors and assembly programming last year. My professor's advice was: "When programming in assembly, don't!"

Comment: @Gregd'Eon, we had a similar saying in the class I TAed: "The first rule of programming in assembly is: don't program in assembly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction you need has the mnemonic CPI (compare with immediate).

This will set or clear a flag depending on the result.

You can then branch after checking the flag.

Have a look at the following example.  It's from the [8-bit] AVR instruction summary (http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf).

The example below is from page 24:

Example:

```
cpi r20,5 ; Compare r20 to the value 5
brbc 1,noteq ; Branch if Zero Flag cleared
...
noteq:nop ; Branch destination (do nothing)
```

There are other instructions that will do slightly different comparisons (like compare two registers, instead of comparing a register with a literal).